# Retrieve all DOM elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My application needs to retrieve all DOM elements in javascript and
and put there values into one variable

i.e

if my application is having three text boxes then i want there values in comma separated form in javascript variable

Comment: You probably really don't want **all** DOM elements, maybe all form elements, or all INPUTs?

Comment: I fear a code smell when you want all field and theIr values into another field. Can you tell us what you need to DO, perhaps we can give you a better solution?

Comment: actually i want to digitally sign DOM object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all DOM elements, which you probably don't, but *if* you do...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

What I think you want is something like this

```
var form = document.getElementById('my-form').

var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');

var inputsCsv = [];

for (var i = 0, length = inputs.length; i < length; i++) {

    if (inputs[i].type === 'text') {
        inputsCsv.push(inputs[i].value);
    }

}

inputsCsv = inputsCsv.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

in below example i am taking values of all textboxes of a table. you can pass  form name there.

```
var frm = document.getElementById('tblemail').getElementsByTagName("input");
var len = frm.length;
var myval='';
for (i=0;i< len;i++)
{
if (frm[i].type == "text")
{
if(myval =='')
{
myval = frm[i].value;
}else{
myval += ',' + frm[i].value;
}
}
}
```